# Improved inverse transform method for Poisson random variable generation in R

Tags: r, poisson

I am reading  **Section 4.2** in `Simulation (2006, 4ed., Elsevier)` by Sheldon M. Ross, which introducing generating a Poisson random variable by  the inverse transform method.

Denote `pi =P(X=xi)=e^{-λ} λ^i/i!, i=0,1,...` and `F(i)=P(X<=i)=Σ_{k=0}^i pi` to be the PDF and CDF for Poisson, respectively, which can be computed via `dpois(x,lambda)` and `ppois(x,lambda)` in R.

There are two inverse transform algorithms for Poisson: **the  regular version** and **the improved one**.

The steps for the  regular version are as follows:

1. Simulate an observation `U` from `U(0,1)​`.
2. Set `i=0​` and `​F=F(0)=p0=e^{-λ}​`.
3. If `U<F​`, select `​X=​i` and terminate.
4. If `U >= F`​, obtain `i=i+1, F=F+pi`​ and return to the previous step.

I write and test the above steps as follows:

```
### write the regular R code
pois_inv_trans_regular = function(n, lambda){
  X = rep(0, n) # generate n samples
  for(m in 1:n){
    U = runif(1)
    i = 0; F = exp(-lambda) # initialize
    while(U >= F){
      i = i+1; F = F + dpois(i,lambda) # F=F+pi
    }
  X[m] = i
  }
X
}
### test the code (for small λ, e.g. λ=3)
set.seed(0); X = pois_inv_trans_regular(n=10000,lambda=3); c(mean(X),var(X))
# [1] 3.005000 3.044079
```

Note that the mean and variance for `Poisson(λ)` are both `λ`,  so the writing and testing for the regular code are making sense!

Next I tried **the improved one**, which is designed for large `λ` and described according to the book as follows:

- The regular algorithm will need to make `1+λ` searches, i.e. `O(λ)` computing complexity, which is fine when `λ` is small, while it can be greatly improved upon when  `λ` is large.
- Indeed, since a Poisson random variable with mean  `λ`  is most likely to take on one of the two integral values closest to  `λ` , a more efficient algorithm would first check one of these values, rather than starting at 0 and working upward. For instance, let `I=Int(λ)` and  recursively determine `F(I)`.
- Now generate a Poisson random variable `X` with mean `λ` by generating a random number `U`, noting whether or not `X <= I​` by seeing whether or not ​`U <= F(I)`​. Then search downward starting from `​I`​ in the case where `X <= I`​ and upward starting from ​`I+1​` otherwise.
- It is said that the improved algorithm only need  `1+0.798√λ` searches, i.e., having `O(√λ)` complexity.

I tried to wirte the R code for the improved one  as follows:

```
### write the improved R code
pois_inv_trans_improved = function(n, lambda){
  X = rep(0, n) # generate n samples
  p = function(x) {dpois(x,lambda)} # PDF: p(x) = P(X=x) = λ^x exp(-λ)/x!
  F = function(x) {ppois(x,lambda)} # CDF: F(x) = P(X ≤ x)
  I = floor(lambda) # I=Int(λ)
  F1 = F(I); F2 = F(I+1) # two close values
  for(k in 1:n){
    U = runif(1)
    i = I
    if ( F1 < U  &  U <= F2 ) { 
      i = I+1 
    } 
    while (U <= F1){ # search downward
      i = i-1; F1 = F1 - p(i)
    }
    while (U > F2){ #  search upward
      i = i+1; F2 = F2 + p(i)
    }
    X[k] = i
  }
  X
}
### test the code (for large λ, e.g. λ=100)
set.seed(0); X = pois_inv_trans_improved(n=10000,lambda=100); c(mean(X),var(X))
# [1] 100.99900000   0.02180118
```

From the simulation results  `[1] 100.99900000   0.02180118` for `c(mean(X),var(X))`, which shows nonsense for the variance part. What should I remedy this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem was that F1 and F2 were modified within the loop and not reset, so eventually a very wide range of U's are considered to be in the middle.
The second problem was on the search downward the p(i) used should be the original i, because F(x) = P(X <= x).  Without this, the code hangs for low U.
The easiest fix for this is to start i = I + 1.  Then "in the middle" if statement isn't needed.

```
pois_inv_trans_improved = function(n, lambda){
  X = rep(0, n) # generate n samples
  p = function(x) {dpois(x,lambda)} # PDF: p(x) = P(X=x) = λ^x exp(-λ)/x!
  `F` = function(x) {ppois(x,lambda)} # CDF: F(x) = P(X ≤ x)
  I = floor(lambda) # I=Int(λ)
  F1 = F(I); F2 = F(I+1) # two close values
  for(k in 1:n){
    U = runif(1)
    i = I + 1
    # if ( F1 < U  &  U <= F2 ) { 
    #   i = I + 1
    # }
    F1tmp = F1
    while (U <= F1tmp){ # search downward
      i = i-1; F1tmp = F1tmp - p(i);  
    }
    F2tmp = F2
    while (U > F2tmp){ #  search upward
      i = i+1; F2tmp = F2tmp + p(i)
    }
    X[k] = i
  }
  X
}
```

This gives:

```
[1] 100.0056 102.2380
```

Comment: Very impressive!  I also check two codes via `(mbm = microbenchmark::microbenchmark(p1 = pois_inv_trans_regular(10000,100),p2 = pois_inv_trans_improved(10000,100),times = 10))`, which verifies that the latter code is indeed faster than the former one! @BrianMontgomery